# Accidentally failing command in linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

I have server and connect to it via ssh, I would like to run command and then disconnect from server thinking, that process is running and will be finished in few hours. 
So I came up with

```
python script.py > output.txt 2^C1 &
```

it works! ... well sometimes .. and sometimes (exactly the same python script) it fails without leaving any error msg in output.txt. Does anyone know why? And what should I be running to prevent failing?

I doubt that it has something to do with python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for nohup.

```
nohup python script.py > output.txt 2^C1 &
```

It allows you to logout with the script still running.

Answer (score 2):

It won't leave any error message in output.txt, Try this

```
python script.py 1> output.txt 2>error.txt 2^C1 &
```

If your script fails it should log reason in error.txt